# Is there a way to skip AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping different URL with bs4, during the scraping the script end up stopping because of an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'. I would like to know if there is a way to skip this error or to return None instead. 
Here's the code:

```
url = 'URL'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tagline = soup.findAll("h2",{"class": "title__xxxxxlarge"}, text=True)[0].text

Features_benefits = [
    x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('div', {"class": "layout-content__section"}).findAll("h3")
]
category = [
    x.text.strip() for x in soup.find("dt", text="Categories").parent.findAll('a')]

regions = [
    x.text.strip() for x in soup.find("dt", text="Geo-Regions").parent.findAll('a')
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the result of `soup.find()` in a variable, and test whether it found anything first.

```
categories = soup.find("dt", text="Categories")
if categories:
    category = [x.text.strip() for x in categories.parent.findAll('a')]
else:
    category = []
```